# Add link to image dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, hyperlink, href

If i have "img" element id = "myimg".
Is posible to add link to "img" without edit html page using jQuery

```
<img id="myimg" src="image.png">
```

I like to make "myimg" have link like this.

```
<a href="test.html"><img id="myimg" src="image.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

```
$("#myimg").wrap("<a href='test.html'></a>');
```

or

```
$("#myimg").wrap($("<a>").attr("href", "test.html"));
```

or:

```
var a = $("<a>").attr("href", "test.html");
$("#myimg").wrap(a);
```

Answer (score 8):

I am not into jQuery. Using Javascript, you can do something like:

```
var parentEl = document.getElementById("myimg").parentElement;
var imgEl = parentEl.innerHtml;
parentEl.innerHtml = '<a href="test.html">' + imgEl + '</a>';
```

Comment: Also how can we remove link i.e. <a> tag if already exist for an image.

Comment: @SamyagShah: You can possibly use a RegEx evaluator and replace the anchors with '' to remove the anchor. That should be quite simple.

Comment: thanks for answer. But is there any other way i.e. by using javascript functions like removeChild,etc.

Comment: That should be posted as a separate question. That might help fellow users, rather than getting it here.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var src = "linkhere.html";
        var a = $("<a/>").attr("href", src);
        $("#myimg").wrap(a);
});
```

Comment: wrap is doing what I tried to achieve using javascript. Definitely +1