# Dynamic link for dynamic pictures

Tags: javascript

I have read this [Add link to image dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400218/add-link-to-image-dynamically) but I would like to have the link dynamic as well.

I tried to have below where `c[idx][13]` would be the dynamic value.

```
$("#img_"+idx).wrap("<a href='https://mylink/'"+c[idx][13]+'></a>');
```

but the quotes are not treated as desired and I am directed to `https://mylink/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to exchange the qoutes like this:

```
$("#img_"+idx).wrap('<a href="https://mylink/'+c[idx][13]+'"></a>');
```