# add a link to a image on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

**EDIT: Wow thanks guys, you guys responded fast, this is my first time using this forum, Thanks a lot. The person who I marked as an answer knew was what I was talking about, to the others also thank for responding**

I was trying to add a link to an image when you hover over it. when you put your cursor over it it changes images and that image has a link. can anyone help me?

**HTML**

```
<img src="don.png" class="artist" onmouseover="hover(this);" onmouseout="unhover(this);" a href="https://privatelink.com"/>
```

**JS**

```
function hover(element) {
  element.setAttribute('src', 'ht.png');
}

function unhover(element) {
  element.setAttribute('src', 'don.png');
}
```

Comment: Just make the `a` element inside the `img` tag and not an attribute of it. `<img><a href=..></a></img>`.

Comment: @cнŝdk The img tag is a void tag, you mean put the img inside the a tag instead

Comment: @SaymoinSam yes my bad, I mixed up things :).

Comment: What will the dynamic element bring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have an error in your html syntax. `a` and `href` are not attributes of an `img` element tag. Check it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) for available attributes. But if you would like to store your custom data with an image, you can add `data-*` attribute. Check it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp). You can then use it in JS if you need it.

From the all solutions at [Add link to image dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400218/add-link-to-image-dynamically) you can use:

```
var parentEl = document.getElementById("myimg").parentElement;
var imgEl = parentEl.innerHtml;
parentEl.innerHtml = '<a href="test.html">' + imgEl + '</a>';
```

... or use jQuery `.wrap()` also mentioned on the link above.

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gjhmzn0w/1/) example for your case.

Answer (score 0):

> you can do like this

**HTML**

```
<img src="don.png" class="artist" id="myImage" onmouseover="hover("myImage")" onmouseout="unhover("myImage")" a href="https://privatelink.com"/>
```

**JS**

```
 function hover(element) {
     document.getElementById(element).src='ht.png'
  }

 function unhover(element) {
     document.getElementById(element).src='don.png'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#myimage").hover(function() {
   var src = "https://privatelink.com";
   var a = $("<a/>").attr("href", src);
    $( this ).wrap(a);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
<figure id="myimage">
  <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Trulli" style="width:100%">
  <figcaption> Fig.1 - Trulli, Puglia, Italy. </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const linkedImg = document.querySelector("#image_link");
linkedImg.addEventListener("mouseover", (evt) => toggleImage(evt, "over"));
linkedImg.addEventListener("mouseout", (evt) => toggleImage(evt, "out"));
function toggleImage(evt, id) {
  if (id === "over") {
    linkedImg.setAttribute("href", "someurl1.html");
    // change image
    linkedImg
      .querySelector("img")
      .setAttribute(
        "src",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542353436-312f0e1f67ff?auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=80"
      );
  } else {
    linkedImg.setAttribute("href", "someurl2.html");
    // change image
    linkedImg
      .querySelector("img")
      .setAttribute(
        "src",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981852-426c6c22a060?fit=crop&w=500&q=80"
      );
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="image_link">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981852-426c6c22a060?fit=crop&w=500&q=80" class="artist"/>
    </a>
```